Given a value that's bound in two places, modify only one of them
Updated to simplify example
I want to change the title text, when either I type in the textfield or tap the button. However I don't want to change the TextField text when I tap the button, just want to change the title text. This is the demo code
struct HobbitView: View {
    @State private var hobbitName = "Bilbo"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //"Place Holder" should not be modified by tapping the button
        TextField("Place Holder", text: $hobbitName)
        
        //Should be modifiable by TextField or Button
        Text("The name is \(hobbitName).")

         //Should only modify the Text, not the TextField text
        Button("Set a Name") {
            hobbitName = "Sam"
        }
    }
}

I guess you may call it "conditional binding". I don't know how else to call it.
I'm new to SwiftUI and I think I'm missing some key knowledge on how SwiftUI bindings work.

if you aren't using Combine or a delegate it's best to use a @State struct instead of @StateObject class

@malhal Heard, thanks. It was part of the simplified example

You need an additional @State to store the text field's text.
Set this to hobbit.firstName initially, and when it changes, update hobbit.firstName.
@StateObject private var hobbit = Hobbit()

@State private var textFieldText = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("Place Holder", text: $textFieldText)
        .padding(.bottom)
        .onAppear {
            textFieldText = hobbit.firstName
        }
        .onChange(of: textFieldText) { _, newValue in
            hobbit.firstName = newValue
        }
    
    
    Text("The name is \(hobbit.firstName).")
        .font(.title)

    
    Button("Set a Name") {
        hobbit.firstName = "Sam"
    }
}

You can wrap this into a custom TextField:
struct HobbitView: View {
    @StateObject private var hobbit = Hobbit()
    
    var body: some View {
        CustomTextField(text: $hobbit.firstName)

        Text("The name is \(hobbit.firstName).")
            .font(.title)
        Button("Set a Name") {
            hobbit.firstName = "Sam"
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    @State private var textFieldText = ""
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Place Holder", text: $textFieldText)
            .padding(.bottom)
            .onAppear {
                textFieldText = text
            }
            .onChange(of: textFieldText) { _, newValue in
                text = newValue
            }
    }
}


Thanks for your input! However the custom field is not updating the "The name is \(foo)"  text as is supposed to. I'm going to tinker with the .onChange, but I feel there should be a more straight forward way

@Ozx sorry about that. I made a typo.

thanks! It worked. Didn't know those existed
